# Local module is not accessed/ can't be loaded in python

Tags: python, module

This is the code of module (loading_module.py) I want to load

```
import sys

def load(file):
    try:
        with open(file) as f:
            loaded_text = f.read().strip().split('\n')
            loaded_text = [x.lower() for x in loaded_text]
            return loaded_text
    except IOError as IO:
        print("{}\n{} cannot be loaded".format(IO, file), file = sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)
```

And when I try to load it I get this:

[image: 1]

So, as I understood it sees the module but it cannot access it for some reason, does anybody know how to resolve it?..

This is what my code looks like:

[image: 2]

So, as you see the module was not loaded and 'load' function is not defined (yellow underlining points at it)

Comment: Please post the code as a text not an image.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are any issues with your code so far.

That error looks like it's saying you're not *using* the `load` function in your code yet.

Try using it somewhere and see if the error disappears.

Comment: I added a pic of code so my issue would be more clearified

Comment: Replace "import loading_module" with "from loading_module import load"

Comment: it gives an ImportError : cannot import name 'load' from 'loading_module' although it does recognize 'load' as a function when I put a cursor on it

Comment: Oh, it worked out properly when I changed the direction of loaded file ('dict.txt'), what was then the difference between 'import loading_module' and 'from loading_module import load'??